# How to change order of source folders in Eclipse / SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am working on a Java Maven project using the SpringSource Tool Suite. I have the standard Maven directory structure

```
src
-> main
   -> java
   -> resources
-> test
   -> java
   -> resources
```

The structure is defined in the .pom file:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

STS displays the source folders in the test branch first and then the source folders from the main branch. So I get something like this:

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

However, I would like to have the folders from the main branch first. Any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: Have you really configured the default Maven convention in your POM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Maven -> Update Project Configuration`.

Comment: What is `Maven`??

Answer (score 63):

In Eclipse it's possible to change the order via project settings.

Right-click `on project -> "project settings" -> Tab "Build Path": "Configure Build Path..."`, tab `"Order and Export"`, use the `"Up"` and `"Down"` buttons to move folders up/down.

Comment: I could not find where to order them in the UI; the Build path dialog allows you to add/remove source folders but that's it.  You can, however, edit the generated .classpath file for the project and change the order in there.

Comment: @flatline Right click on the project, "Build Path" > "Configure Build Path...", tab "Order and Export", use the "Up" and "Down" buttons.

Comment: Maven -> Update Project, did not work for me. This worked perfectly, cheers

Comment: I suggest adding sp00m's comment details to this answer. (And thanks, sp00m!)

Comment: @proko & sp00m, I am not seeing either of these options ("project settings" or "Build Path") after right clicking on my project. In which version of eclipse are you seeing this? I'm on Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version 2.0.2.20140224-0000